# RxJS - Create Auto-Complete Observable That First Returns Data From Cache And Then From Server

Tags: javascript, angular, autocomplete, rxjs, observable

I found this article that explains how I can use RxJs to create an observable for auto-complete:
https://blog.strongbrew.io/building-a-safe-autocomplete-operator-with-rxjs

```js
const autocomplete = (time, selector) => (source$) =>
  source$.pipe(
    debounceTime(time),
    switchMap((...args: any[]) => 
      selector(...args)
        .pipe(
            takeUntil(
                source$
                    .pipe(
                        skip(1)
                    )
            )
        )
    )
  )
  
  
    term$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  results$ = this.term$.pipe(
        autocomplete(1000, (term => this.fetch(term)))
    )
```

I want to improve this auto-complete observable by first returning data from local storage and display it to the user and then continue to the server to fetch data. The data that will be returned from the server will not replace the one the result from the local storage but will be added to it. 
If I understand it correctly on each time the user types, there observable should emit twice.

How can I build it in the most efficient way?
Kind Regards,
Tal Humy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after dealing with this for a few hours, I figured out that the solution was very straightforward:

```js
        autocomplete(1000, (term => new Observable(s => {
          const storageValue = this.fetchFromStorage(term);
          s.next(storageValue);
          this.fetchFromServer(term)
            .subscribe(r => s.next(r));
        })))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take advantage of `startWith`.

```
const term$ = new BehaviorSubject('');
const localStorageResults = localStorage.getItem(''); // Map it into the same shape as results$ but the observable unwrapped
const results$ = term$
    .pipe(
        startWith(localStorageResults),
        debounceTime(1000),
        switchMap(term => 
            getAutocompleteSuggestions(term)
                .pipe(
                    takeUntil(
                        //skip 1 value
                        term$.pipe(skip(1))
                    )

                )
            )
        )
    )
```

You may have to tinker with that, I am not sure if it will play nice with the `debounceTime` but it's an idea.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. This is a link for an online editor if you are willing to give it a shot :) 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/safe-switchmap